# Closed range for maps between banach spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about Fredholm operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146723/question-about-fredholm-operator)

This seems to be a standard result but I cannot find the solution.
Let $M:X \rightarrow U$ be a bounded linear map between two Banach spaces. Assume that the range is a finite -codimensional subspace of U; then the range is closed.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146723/question-about-fredholm-operator) for a solution.

Comment: But here we dont have $Ker(M)$ with finite dimension @DavidMitra

Comment: @Tomás I linked the wrong post. It's corrected now; point 3. of t.b.'s answer is relevant.

Comment: Yes @DavidMitra, the answer is there.