# Bounded operators with prescribed range

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $X$ is a **seaparable** Banach space and $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, not necessarily closed, can one always find an **bounded** operator with range $Y$? It is easy when $Y$ is closed and complemented, what if it's not?

Edit 1: I modified the question to add that $X$ is separable. It seems that the general case is open.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101253/surjectivity-of-operators-on-linfty

Edit 2: If $Y$ is not closed, Jonas Meyer answer below shows that the answer is 'No'. What about when $Y$ is closed?

Edit 3: A followup question has been posted about the case when $Y$ is closed: [Bounded operators with prescribed range - part II](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/475887/)

Comment: Could you clarify this for me -- must the range of the operator include all of Y or could there be a y in Y such that y is not in L(X)? Or perhaps the answer is trivial of all of Y is not included?

Comment: another thought -  a bounded operator must be continuous, and if Y is open wouldn't any continuous operator that covers Y also cover the closure of Y?

Comment: +1 Good question. In the simplest case where $Y$ is one-dimensional, the answer, Hahn-Banach, is already non-trivial.

Comment: @BettyMock I want Range(T)=$Y$. When not all of $Y$ is included, you can simply take a finite dimensional subspace of $Y$. I don't know whether it is easier when you require an infinite dimensional subspace of $Y$.

Comment: @BettyMock Proper subspaces of a topological vector space (TVS) always have empty interior, so $Y$ cannot be open. Even if you mean "not-close" instead of "open", what you say is still not true. Bounded operators can have non-closed ranges.

Comment: @Michael When $Y$ is closed and complemented, in particular when $Y$ is one-dimensional, then one can simply defined $T$ as the identity on $Y$ and $0$ on the complement. I think you are right, to show that every finite dimensional subspace is complemented, one needs HB.

Comment: @BettyMock: the simplest example is on a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$, the operator $e_n\mapsto \frac1n\,e_n$ is compact with dense (but non-closed) range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In part 3 of [t.b.'s answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146990/) it is shown that if a bounded operator between Banach spaces has finite codimensional range, then it has closed range.  If $Y$ is the kernel of an unbounded linear functional $X\to\mathbb C$, then $Y$ has finite codimension but is not closed, hence $Y$ is not the range of a bounded operator.

This is generalized in ["Algebraic complements and ranges of linear operators"](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZwIvfsGhzOYC&pg=PA87]) by Enflo and Smith, 2011, where the main result is stated as follows:

> Let $B$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space and let $C$ be any non-empty, closed subspace of $B$ whose algebraic complement, $N$, is non-closed.  Then, $N$ is not the range of a continuous linear operator on a Banach space.

Comment: What of $Y$ is closed? I will accept this answer to my question, as it would be unfair to keep moving the goalpost :)

Comment: @Markus: Just to clarify, the domain is $X$, right?

Comment: Yes, $T$ is supposed to be a bounded operator acting on $X$.

Comment: @Markus: I don't know, but I added a generalization of my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. As they say in the last sentence of the first section, it looks as the question is, to a large extent, an open problem.

Comment: @Markus: Perhaps it would be worthwhile to ask about the case where $Y$ is closed as a separate question.