# Given $ST$ Fredholm then $T$ is Fredholm iff $S$ is , in Banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y,Z$ be Banach spaces.
$T\in B(X,Y), S\in B(Y,Z)$ and $ST$ is Fredholm.
Show that $T$ is Fredholm iff $S$ is Fredholm.

I saw here possible answers for a similar question however it did not use the definition of Fredholm operators, but the characteristic and algebra...
[Composition of Fredholm Operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290377/composition-of-Fredholm-operators)

Comment: Saying that this is "not relevant to your studies" is quite a strong statement. It's of course legitimate to ask for alternative proofs, but the ones to the linked question are both quite elegant, so I wouldn't dismiss them so easily.

Comment: Sorry maybe i did not explain what i meant well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is Fredholm. Then there exists a bounded operator $A:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $$AT-I=K_{1T}$$ $$TA-I=K_{2T}$$ where $K_{1T},K_{2T}$ are compact.

Similarly, since $ST$ is also Fredholm, there exists a bounded operator $B:Z \rightarrow X$ such that $$BST-I=K_{1ST}$$ $$STB-I=K_{2ST}$$ where $K_{1ST},K_{2ST}$ are compact.

Consider the operator $D=TB:Z\rightarrow Y$. Then we already know that $SD-I=K_{2ST}$ which is compact. On the other hand, we have

$$DS-I=TBS-I=TBS(TA-K_{2T})-I=TBSTA-TBSK_{2T}-I=$$ $$T(K_{1ST}+I)A-TBSK_{2T}-I=TK_{1ST}A+TA-TBSK_{2T}-I$$ $$=TK_{1ST}A+K_{2T}+I-TBSK_{2T}-I=$$ $$TK_{1ST}A+K_{2T}-TBSK_{2T}$$
Since the compact operators form an ideal in the bounded operators, $TK_{1ST}A+K_{2T}-TBSK_{2T}$ is compact and we are done.

The other direction is proven similarly.