# On Fredholm operator on Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $u: H \to H'$ be a continuous linear operator and $H,H'$ be Hilbert spaces. Let $u^\ast$ denotes its adjoint.

By definition, an operator $u$ is called Fredholm if and only if $\ker u$ has finite dimension and $\mathrm{im}(u)$ has finite codimension.

My book states that

"...$u$ is Fredholm if and only if $u(H)$ is closed and $\ker u$ and $\ker u^\ast$ are both finite dimensional"

I am not sure but I beleive that closedness of $u(H)$ is redundant, that is, the following is true:

$u$ is Fredholm if and only if $\ker u$ and $\ker u^\ast$ are finite-dimensional.

My proof:

$\implies$: If $u$ is Fredholm then by definition $\ker u$ is finite dimensional. Also, $(u(H))^\bot =\ker u^\ast$. If $V$ is a vector space and $U$ a subspace then the dimension of all complements of $U$ are equal, in particular, equal to the orthogonal complement. Hence $\ker u^\ast$ is finite dimensional.

$\Longleftarrow$: Let $\ker u$ and $\ker u^\ast$ be finite dimensional. By the same argument as before, $u(H)$ has finite codimension. Since $\ker u$ is finite dimensional it follows that $u$ is Fredholm.

> Where is the mistake in my proof? What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm confused by your proof.  If the definition of "$u$ is Fredholm" is "$u(H)$ is closed, $\ker u$ is finite dimensional, and $\ker u^*$ is finite dimensional", then the $\implies$ direction of your theorem is trivial.  And in the reverse direction I don't see that you have even tried to show that having $\ker u$ and $\ker u^*$ finite dimensional implies that $u(H)$ is closed (and indeed this implication is not true).

Comment: Whether $u(H)$ has finite codimension depends on how you define "codimension".  Either way, it doesn't imply that $u(H)$ is closed.

Comment: As a counterexample, there are plenty of operators that are injective and have dense range (so that the adjoint is injective) but do not have closed range.  One example is the operator $u$ on $L^2([0,1])$ defined by $(uf)(x) = xf(x)$.

Comment: @NateEldredge No the definition is different, I added it to my question.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that "$u(H)^\perp$ has finite dimension" does not imply "$u(H)$ has finite codimension".

"Codimension" is meant in the algebraic sense.  For a (not necessarily closed) linear subspace $E \subset H$, "$E$ has finite codimension" means (among other equivalent definitions) "there exists a finite dimensional subspace $F \subset H$ such that for every $x \in H$, there exist unique $y \in E$, $z \in F$ such that $x=y+z$".  In other words, $H = E \oplus F$ as a direct sum of vector spaces.

Let's consider the example I gave in my comment: $H = L^2((0,1))$ (it's simpler if we leave off the endpoints) and $u$ defined by $(uf)(x) = xf(x)$.  Note that $u$ is injective since if $uf = 0$ we have $x f(x) = 0$ and hence $f(x) = 0$ for almost every $x \in (0,1)$.  So $\ker u = 0$ which is finite dimensional.

It's easy to check that $u$ is self-adjoint, so we have $\ker u^* = \ker u = 0$ as well.

Also, we can see directly that $u(H)^\perp = 0$.  Suppose $g \in u(H)^\perp$; then in particular $\langle ug, g \rangle = 0$.  This says that $\int_0^1 x g(x)^2\,dx = 0$, so that $x g(x)^2 = 0$ and hence $g(x) = 0$ almost everywhere.

But $u(H)$ has infinite codimension.  For $0 < p < 1/2$, let $f_p(x) = x^{-p}$.  Note that $f_p \notin u(H)$ since if we had $u g_p = f_p$, we would have to have $g_p(x) = x^{-p-1}$ almost everywhere; but those functions are not in $L^2((0,1))$.  Moreover, the uncountable set of functions $\{f_p\}$ is linearly independent.  So if we let $F$ be the linear span of all the $\{f_p\}$, then $F$ has infinite (even uncountable) dimension and $u(H) \cap F = 0$; the codimension of $u(H)$ is infinite (even uncountable).

So for this operator $u$, we have that $\ker u$ and $\ker u^*$ are both finite dimensional (actually zero dimensional) but $u$ is not Fredholm.

Another way to think about the issue is that the orthogonal complement $E^\perp$ is not in general an algebraic complement of $E$; it's an algebraic complement of the *closure* of $E$.  (You may be confused since in finite dimensions, $E^\perp$ is an algebraic complement of $E$; but in finite dimensions all linear subspaces are closed.)  In particular, having $E^\perp = 0$ does not imply $E = H$; it only implies that $E$ is dense in $H$, but dense subspaces can still have large codimension.

As a final remark, it is not true in general that a linear subspace $E$ with finite codimension is closed (consider the kernel of a discontinuous linear functional, which has codimension 1).  However, it is true in the special case that $E$ is the image of a continuous operator on a complete space.

Comment: In the second paragraph, why is $f(x) =0$ only for *almost* every $x \in (0,1)$?

Comment: @student: Maybe the phrasing could have been clearer: from $uf=0$ we can only conclude that $x f(x) = 0$ for almost every $x$, and for those $x$ we have $f(x)=0$.

Comment: I am sorry if my questions are stupid, I am really trying to understand this. Regarding the very first sentence in your answer: it seems to contradict the sentence from Encyclopedia of Maths that I quote [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106325/how-to-define-orthogonal-complement-in-an-arbitrary-vector-space). The encyclopedia claims that all the complements have the same dimension... or at least it is how I understand it. (I am now about to study the second half of your answer, maybe it will already resolve my confusion....)

Comment: But $uf = 0$ if and only if $x f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. And because $x f(x) = 0$ implies that $f(x)=0$ (since $x\neq 0$) it follows that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. What is wrong with this argument?

Comment: @student: When I say "$uf=0$", I mean "equal as elements of $L^2([0,1])$".  Remember that formally, the elements of $L^2([0,1])$ are equivalence classes of functions mod almost everywhere equality.  To be very pedantic, I should have defined $u([f])$ to be $[g]$ where $g$ is the function defined by $g(x)=xf(x)$, and verified that this is well defined.  Then saying "$uf=0$" really means $u([f]) = [0]$, that is, the equivalence class $u([f])$ is the equivalence class of 0.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Regarding the Encyclopedia of Mathematics article: it's poorly written, since in a general vector space there is no notion of an orthogonal complement.  In any vector space $X$, a complement of a vector subspace $E$ is, as in my second paragraph, a subspace $F$ such that for any $x \in X$ there exist unique $y \in E, z \in F$ such that $x=y+z$.  In a Hilbert space, if $E$ is a closed subspace, then the orthogonal complement is a complement in this sense, but as my example shows, that is not true if $E$ is not closed.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand the sentence in the article. It seems to me that the sentence if wrong since you give an example of a map such that the complement does not have the same dimension as the orthogonal complement. But the sentence in the Encyclopedia claims that these would have to be equal. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Although your proof is not right, your statement that closedness of u(H) is redundant in the definition of Fredholm operator is true, in that

> $H/uH$ is finite-dimensional implies $uH$ is closed.

*Proof*. Suppose that $[e_1],\cdots,[e_n]$ is a basis of $H/uH$, and $H_0=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}\subset H.$ Then $H=uH\oplus H_0$.($e_1,\cdots,e_n\notin uH$, so $H_0\cap uH=\{0\};$ for any $h\in  H$, suppose $[h]=k_1[e_1]+\cdots+ k_n[e_n]$, then $h-k_1e_1-\cdots-k_ne_n\in uH$ because $[h-k_1e_1-\cdots-k_ne_n]=[h]-[h]=0$, thus $H=uH+H_0$.)

Let $\Phi: H/\ker u\times H_0\to H(=uH\oplus H_0), (h+\ker u,k)\mapsto uh+k$, then $\Phi$ is a continuous linear bijection:

(1)$\Phi$ is well-defined. If $(h+\ker u, k)=(h'+\ker u, k')$, then $h-h'\in \ker u$ and $k=k'$, so $u(h)+k=u(h')+k'$.

(2)$\Phi$ is injective. If $h\in H$ and $k\in H_0$ satisfy $uh+k=0$, then $uh=0$ and $k=0$ for $H=uH\oplus H_0$, i.e., $(h+\ker u,k)=0$

(3)$\Phi$ is surjective. Of course.

Since that $H_0$ is finite-dimensional, $H/\ker u\oplus H_0$ is a Banach space, so we can apply the Open Mapping Theorem to $\Phi$, $\Phi$ has a continuous linear invert $\Phi^{-1}$, and thus is bounded below. Hence $uH=\Phi(H/\ker u\times \{0\})$ is closed.