Fredholm operator bijectivity
Let X and Y are infinite dimension Hilbert space and continuous a Fredholm operator $D:X\to Y$ of index $0$. I have that $D$ is injective and the formal adjoint is injective too. Thus im(D) is dense in $Y$. How can show the subjectivity of D?
In my case I have that D is the direct operator and $X = W^{1,2}$ and $Y = L^2$.

The range of Fredholm operators is closed. Thus, dense image implies surjective.

See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670/is-the-closedness-of-the-image-of-a-fredholm-operator-implied-by-the-finiteness

The proof must be something like this?
Since $C^\infty \subset W^{1,2}\subset L^2$ and dense. We have that the image of the Dirac operator is going to be dense in $L^2$. In addition D is Fredholm we have that the image is closed. Then we can show by contradiction that D is surjective. We can conclude that D is bijective.
Is this correct ?

If you know that a Fredholm operator $A$ with Fredholm index $0$ is injective, then you knwo that $0=\mathrm{dim}(Ker A) = \mathrm{dim}(Coker A)$. Thus, $A$ has dense range. However, as it is a Fredholm operator, the range is closed too. Thus, $\mathrm{Im}(A)$ is dense and closed, i.e. $\mathrm{Im}(A)=Y$ and therefore $A$ is surjective. This argument tells you that a Fredholm operator with Fredholm index $0$ is injective iff it is bijective (in fact this is also equivalent to being surjective). This also goes by the name Fredholm alternative.

@SeverinSchraven Thank you very much.

I suggest that you spell out your insights in an answer in the box below. Then you can get feedback from the community and it might help future visitors of this site.

We have that $C^\infty \subset W^{1,2}\subset L^2$ and dense and the index of D is 0. Then the image of the Dirac operator is going to be dense in $L^2$. Since D is Fredholm we have that the image is closed. Then we obtain that the image is the total. Therefore we obtain that D is bijective.
